# Apache ZooKeeper WEB-UI

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Is there any web-interface to check the data (or tree) present in the zookeeper?

CLI is bit hard to get the complete picture of the tree and data.

Comment: https://github.com/soabase/exhibitor/wiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can browse ZNode hierarchy from Hue (if configured properly). Check http://gethue.com/new-zookeeper-browser-app/ for demo video and some details on how to set it up.

Answer (score 19):

Yes there is. [ZooNavigator](https://www.elkozmon.com/zoonavigator/) is a web app that enables you to browse and edit data in ZooKeeper.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15958450)

Comment: @JigneshAnsodariya I edited my post to answer the question more closely, even though it was far from a "link-only" answer before.

Comment: I am facing de documented problem on the Git page "Unable to establish connection with ZooKeeper." but can't figure out how to fix it. Could you please point me what I should Google in order to sort this out? Thank you!

Comment: @LucasRezende I assume you are using ZooNavigator via Docker, if so you have to make sure ZooKeeper is reachable from ZooNavigator API container using the exact same address you enter in the connection form since that container might be running on different network than ZooKeeper. If you need further help feel free to [raise an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/elkozmon/zoonavigator/issues) and we can talk there.

Answer (score 8):

The upcoming Zookeeper 3.5.0 will have a built in "Admin Server" interface at localhost:8080. You may have to enable or configure it to get it running. As of 2017-01-30 the current/stable version is 3.4.9 and 3.5.0 is labeled as being "alpha".

Update: as of 2018-02-20 this feature still has't been released. It's now in 3.5.3 beta. The links have been updated but they may not remain active as the version number changes.

[Admin Server Documentation](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.3-beta/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_adminserver)

[Admin Server Configuration](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.3-beta/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_adminserver_config)

Comment: links are broken

Comment: @hariszhr The links have been updated but they may change as this is unreleased feature. Thanks.

Comment: 3.5.5 has been released and Admin Server is present https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.5/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_adminserver

Comment: Isn't this a per Zookeeper HTTP server exclusively for administering that instance? What if I wanted something to inspect/monitor the whole cluster?

Answer (score 3):

zk-web is a git project that will help you. Check below link for more

[zk-web](https://github.com/qiuxiafei/zk-web)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try this:
https://github.com/XiaoMi/shepher

Features:

> Visualized operation of ZooKeeper node
>
> Snapshot management of ZooKeeper node
>
> Modified Diff and Review function of ZooKeeper node
>
> Mail operation notification of ZooKeeper node
>
> CAS and LDAP integration

Answer (score 2):

Might be late to game, but found this if you want an easy way to view zookeeper data/stuff:

https://github.com/migcaraballo/inspectorZk-v1

Answer (score 0):

There is a Java app "Zooinspector" that allows browsing/creating nodes and view/edit data with syntax highlighting and code folding for XML etc, here: https://github.com/CycleMost/zooinspector